# C++ Error - <unnamed-tag>an in-cass initializer is not allowed for a member of an anonymous union

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

My first post here, thanks in advance.
Im new to C++ and am struggling with this mistake.

```
typedef struct {
    int x;
    int z;
    char ref[20]; // or of other adequate type
    DATE date;
    bool put;
    int hasPiece = false;

} TRequest;
```

And when i build it displays the error in the title

> `"<unnamed-tag>::hasPiece' : an in-class initializer is not allowed for a member of an anonymous union in non-class scope.`

Can you please help me?? Thanks so much

Comment: why would you tag `C#`?!

Comment: This is not c# code, do not tag it as such

Comment: You know that structure names, as well as class names, are automatically defined as type-names, right? So you don't need `typedef` in C++ for structures or classes. Perhaps you need [a good beginners book to read](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)?

Comment: And are you *sure* you posted the right code? The error message and the code you show doesn't match. The error message talks about a `union` but the code you show is a `struct`. Please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: So sorry, already deleted the tag. Well when i double click the error it sends me to that line in this struct i just copied in here! 
Im totally new to C++ sorry

Comment: Is this entire struct in a union?

Comment: Which compiler are you using?

Comment: @MikelF i don't know. i just started the c++ classes, they provided the students with a copy of microsoft visual studio. I didnt installed any additional compilers i think

Comment: @Borgleader This isnt a union i think, its just a regular struct and im only getting this error. Can you help me or tell me where to get help? im kinda desperate. Thanks!!

Comment: In older versions of C++, you weren't allowed to provide default values for class members. Which version of Visual Studio are you using?

Comment: @Quentin 2013. should iget the newer one?

Comment: @RarestPep well, if you can. Otherwise, remove the `= false` from your class definition and write a default constructor that sets the default values.

Answer (score 0):

In c++98 you're not allowed to give default values to members of a struct, although you may be able to in later standards. Use this approach instead:

```
struct TRequest 
{
    TRequest()
      : hasPiece(0)
    {
      // Nothing to do here
    }

    int x;
    int z;
    char ref[20]; // or of other adequate type
    DATE date;
    bool put;
    int hasPiece;
};
```

Note that you should be initalising all of the other members too, not just hasPiece. I've also fixed some other bits, you didn't need the typedef.

EDIT: Just noticed hasPiece is an int, why are you initialising it to false? It should be a bool, or initialised to 0. I've changed my answer to initialise it to 0.